# Definition of an ordered ring - isn't it luck which "half" we get as positive?

Tags: abstract-algebra

**EDIT** I think "I want to prove $D^+$ is unique" might be better as a question, somehow this definition filters the negative from positive. (think of the graph z=xy, there is some notion of positive fundamental to the ring you plot the graph on, not because of the numbers you use)

I've just been given the following definition:

An integral domain $D$ is said to be an ordered integral domain if $D$ has a subset, $D^+$, where the following hold:

1. If $a,b\in D^+$ then $a+b\in D^+$
2. If $a,b\in D^+$ then $ab\in D^+$
3. $\forall a\in D$ exactly one of the following holds:

   - $a=0$
   - $a\in D^+$
   - $-a\in D^+$

Now I have proved previously that $(-a)(-b)=ab$ for a ring.

My question is if I get this set we call $D^+$ does it actually have "the positive ones" in it.

One of my favourite proofs is "for a ring $R$, $\forall a\in R: 0a=a0=0$ - this shows that the simple definition of a ring must give you this notion of 0 (if you want the distributivity rules, you get a 0 that has this property).

Here, where does the notion of negative come from? There'll be some $x$ say, where $x^2$ is in the set that $x$ isn't in (negative x will take you to positive) but the $-x$ notion is arbitrary. $x$ and $-x$ are inverses of each other, we could call $x$ the inverse of $-x$ or $-x$ the inverse of $x$, the $-$ sign just means "the thing that when added to this without the - sign gives 0"

I can see that $a,b\in D^+\implies ab\in D^+$ might lead to something about $a^2>0$ and we've defined something as positive if $a-b\in D^+$ but I can't quite see it.

I sense I am very close to something nicer than what I said about 0, but I can't quite see it. Bit of a non-question "what makes negative negative" but I am so close to something, I can feel it!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan we're not dealing with numbers, we're dealing with elements. Somehow this $D^+$ contains "positive" ones, - this definition rules out negative ones. I'd like to prove this $D^+$ is unique, I think.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "negative ones," and by "number" I mean "element of $D$."

Comment: "We've defined something as positive if..." is wrong. $D^+$ is the positive elements of the ring, you and define $a>b$ if $a-b\in\mathbb D^+$ - that is, if $a-b$ is positive. You aren't defining "positive" there, you are defining $a>b$.

Comment: You now have two answers showing $D^+$ is not unique in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a trick of language, rather than math. English language gives us a system of naming many integers satisfying $x > 0$. Thus, the most convenient way to name the integers satisfying $x < 0$ is through stating that they are the additive inverse of a number we can name: i.e. because we have named something "one", we would name its inverse "negative one".

Note that if $x < 0$, then "negative $x$" is actually a *positive* number.

---

Rings can have many different orderings. An instructive example is the ring of all numbers that can be written in the form

$$ a + b \sqrt{2} $$

where $a,b$ are integers. This has the usual ordering $\leq$ on the real numbers. It also has another ordering which I will call $\preceq$ given by

$$ a + b \sqrt{2} \preceq c + d\sqrt{2} \iff a - b \sqrt{2} \leq c - d \sqrt{2} $$

I believe that in general, in an orderable ring, only the sums of squares are "intrinsicially" positive in the sense that they are positive in *every* ordering of the ring. Their negations would be "intrinsically" negative. Any other nonzero element would be positive in some orderings and negative in other orderings.

(if this isn't true in general, it's at least true for some interesting class of rings I can't remember)

Comment: On the other hand, I think the ordering on a real closed field (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) is unique - the positive (really non-negative) elements are precisely the squares, or equivalently the sums of squares.

Comment: No, because $1$ is always positive, as you have been told. Proof: assume $1$ is negative, then $1^2=1$ is positive, contradiction. $1$ is never $0$, so $1$ is positive QED.

Comment: @trb4564 - thanks I mean this sincerely, that helps.

Comment: @trb456 that really probably was the single most useful thing I've gotten from this. The multiplicative identity of a ring with unity serves to orient or anchor $D^+$, without it (as in the example given above) it isn't unique, together you answered my question - thanks ever so much, sincerely.

Comment: In English the symbol "$-x$" is read as "minus one".

Answer (score 3):

Consider the integral domain $D=\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-2)$. 
For any injective ring homomorphism $f\colon D\to \mathbb R$ we can let $D^+=f^{-1}((0,\infty)$, i.e. we declare an element of $D$ positive iff its image under $f$ is a positve real number.
Now note that we have two obvios ring honmomorphism $D\to \mathbb R$, one given by $\overline X\mapsto \sqrt 2$, one given by $\overline X\mapsto -\sqrt 2$, hence we have two distinct notions positiveness, two distinct choices of $D^+$. This shows that positiveness is not an absolute property of all elements of $D$ (but it is for some, e.g. $1=1^2$ implies $1\in D^+$ for all choices of $D^+$).

Answer (score 2):

It's not arbitrary because a square should be positive. In particular, $1$ should be positive. (You would be correct if you were talking about ordered abelian groups - that is, if you were just talking about addition - but the particular form that compatibility with multiplication takes breaks the symmetry.)

Comment: Why must a square be positive? $aa\in D^+$ as I said. but $(-a)(-a)\in D^+$ too what, makes $(-a)$ not be in $D^+$?

Comment: @Alec: $-a$ is a square root, not a square. The square of any element of $D$ is positive by trichotomy: if $a$ is positive then $a^2$ is a product of two positive elements and so positive, but if $a$ is negative then $-a$ is positive, so $a^2 = (-a)^2$ is a product of two positive elements and so positive.

Comment: Where have you pulled square-root from? I've not defined $a^m$ for $m\notin\mathbb{N_0}$

Comment: @Alec: then I don't understand what you mean by "what makes $-a$ not be in $D^{+}$?" ($a$ is a square root of $x$ if $a^2 = x$. This definition only requires that you know what squaring means.) I think you should stop assuming that I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AlecTeal Really, that is way out of bounds, and the kind of behavior that can get you banned

Comment: Sorry, going "I don't understand what negative is" and saying "1 is positive" wasn't very helpful.

Comment: @Alec: I think I may have misunderstood your question. I understood your original question to mean something like "what's to stop me from writing down an order where everything that's usually positive is negative and vice versa?" and the short answer to that question is "$1$ is always positive." Was I mistaken?

Comment: @AlecTeal, your general tone here is not quite what we expect from users...